Homotopy relations between surfaces with boundary and submanifolds of dimension 2
Let $\Sigma(g,n)$ denote the oriented surface of genus $g$ with $n$ boundary components.
Consider $X=\Sigma(g',n')$ a submanifold of $\Sigma=\Sigma(g,n)$, $g'\leq g$ and $n'\leq n$.
Question: for an inclusion $i$, when is $i^*:\pi_1(X)\to\pi_1(\Sigma)$ such that it maps a (minimal) set of generators of $\pi_1(X)$ to a subset of some (minimal) set of generators of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$?
Subquestion: Is there a better way to say that in a group-theoretic way?
Clearly, if $X=\Sigma(0,2)$ and $\Sigma=\Sigma(1,1)$ this is not true. It is easy to find counterexamples: simply take a tubular neighbourhood of a closed curve realising $(2,0)\in \mathbb{Z}^2= H_1(\Sigma)$. But I think that is the only relevant case: if $g=0$, always; if $g>0$ then $g'>0$ or $n'>2$ (or both).
I was thinking in terms of pants decomposition when $g>0$, since the case of a cylinder is the only one that is not covered. Take a pant decomposition of $X$ and complete it to a pants decomposition of $\Sigma$, and I think one can give a presentation of the fundamental group in terms of pants decomposition. Is this idea correct?
How do you show the case $g=0$ and $g'=0,n'=2$?
I also have the feeling that this must be somewhere.
Thanks!

Huh? As soon as $n \geq 1$, $\Sigma = \Sigma(g, n)$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of copies of $S^1$, therefore $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is free. Thus, assuming $n, n' > 0$ your map $i^*$ is a map between free groups; in particular its image is a free group of rank at most that of $\pi_1(X)$, and since that's less than or equal to that of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ by assumption the answer to your question is always "yes."

As for "Clearly, if [...] this is not true. It is easy to find counterexamples." you should probably tell us what "clear" argument you had in mind, and tell us what it means to "find" a counterexample in the first place: After all $i$ is a fixed inclusion, so if you fix all of $g$, $g'$, $n$, and $n'$ there is no more room to go searching for anything.

@BenSteffan Your first comment is very right, sorry. What I want to avoid is for example a map from the cylinder to $\Sigma(1,1)$ that sends the generator of the $\pi_1$ of the cylinder to twice one generator of the $\pi_1$ of $\Sigma(1,1)$. Is my edit better?
I included this example too.

"the set of generators of $\pi_1(X)$" is sort of meaningless on its own: Every element can be part of a generating set. You should specify explicitly which generators you mean (e.g. the "standard generators" of $\pi_1(\Sigma(g, 0))$ together with the classes of the boundary components). I'm also still confused about $i$: You don't want to consider some fixed, canonical inclusion $i$, right, even though you say "the inclusion $i$"? Rather you want to ask about all possible inclusions/embeddings. Finally, in your counterexample, $H_1(\Sigma) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$, not $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

@BenSteffan well, it should be "a" set of generators of $\pi_1(X)$ and "an" inclusion, you are right. And by set of generators I mean minimal set of generators. Finally, that is a typo, I wanted to write $\Sigma(1,1)$. That retracts to two $S^1$.
